# How to make Alfred switch to currently open Chrome instead of opening a new window?

Tags: google-chrome, alfred

This used to be the normal behavior for me:

1. I have a Chrome window A open
2. The focus is in another program window B
3. I bring up Alfred and type Chrome
4. Chrome is the first result, selected by default
5. I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and...
6. The focus goes to the already-opened Chrome window A

That's the same as doing Command-Tab if there are only two windows open, each of a different applications. **This is how I'd like it to behave.**

Now I don't know what I did wrong to make this change (or if it was me at all), but this is what happens now:

1. I have a Chrome window A open
2. The focus is in another program window B
3. I bring up Alfred and type Chrome
4. Chrome is the first result, selected by default
5. I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (nothing different so far) and...
6. A **new Chrome window C** gets opened *behind* program window B
7. Focus remains on program window B

This doesn't happen with Firefox, for example, where the expected behavior continues working.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same exact issue, and checked for a MacOS update and didn't have one. It turned to be fixed with a Chrome update.

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Comment: I'm using Quicksilver triggers to open Chrome and I had the same issue, where instead of switching to the currently open window, it would open a new one. Fixed by upgrading to latest Chrome as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I just tried it and it's doing the desired behavior for me (opens the currently open window).

Only thing I can think of is that Alfred is opening another instance of Chrome because you have 2 chrome installations. Try this:

- Command-click on the Chrome icon on the dock. This will open that Chrome's install location.
- Open Alfred, search for Chrome, click right arrow, and choose "Reveal in Finder".
- Check if both locations are the same.

Comment: Thank you for trying to reproduce it. It kind of fixed itself, I just have no idea how or what was the problem before. A new macOS update came by, I installed it, restarted the computer, and things went back to normal ‍♂️. Should I just delete the question?

Comment: Please don't delete the question. Your comment of restarting worked for me!

Comment: This was the issue for me thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, however for Chrome Canary. The problem isn't reproducible for any of the other browsers I've tested: Chrome, Firefox, Firefox Dev. And I've tried updating OSX and Google Canary. What fixed it was to remove the entire application and reinstalling Canary.